# The token endpoint is not getting called Even after getting authorization_code

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I have used spring-security and oauth2-client dependency.
Homepage url:

```
http://localhost:9090/webpage/
```

application.properties file configuration

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.fedsso.client-id=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.fedsso.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.fedsso.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.fedsso.redirect-uri=http://localhost:9090/webpage/
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.fedsso.issuer-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.fedsso.authorization-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.fedsso.token-uri=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.fedsso.user-info-uri=
```

Created Bean of SecurityFilterChain

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.oauth2Login();
return http.build();
```

The network tab debug results:

```
1.http://localhost:9090/webpage/ - redirect
2.http://localhost:9090/webpage/oauth2/authorization/fedsso - redirect
3./authorization.ouath2 - redirect
4.http://localhost:9090/webpage/?code=auth_code&state=qwasda - redirect
```

then after 4th redirect spring should call the token endpoint for getting access_token/Id_token in exchange for authorization_code
But what is happening that after 4th point it is redirecting again to 2nd point i.e fedsso then 3rd point authorization.oauth2 then 4th point again then it is repeating from 2nd point to 4th point

Validated the authorization code grant flow in postman/insomnia(for getting the access_token/id_token) and i'm able to get the tokens by providing configuration.

Comment: have you tested the flow in postman/insomnia?

Comment: yeah added the point in question